# Visual Studio weirdness: C++ program dreadfully slower in VS 2010 than 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I have the following program (this code is a scaled down version from a google code jam problem I was practicing).

When running this program on VS 2008, it runs in **10.459** seconds.
On VS 2010, it runs in **47.073** seconds. I tried it running with and without debugging, and the times were similar.

Why the huge disparity?

Here are the **compiler** command lines (I'm just using defaults from creating new C++ console app in Visual Studio, but I put these here anyway in case someone needs to see them).

VS 2008

```
/Od /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /Gm /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc90.pdb" /W3 /nologo /c /ZI /TP /errorReport:prompt
```

VS 2010

```
/ZI /nologo /W3 /WX- /Od /Oy- /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /Gm /EHsc /RTC1 /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fp"Debug\myproj2.pch" /Fa"Debug\" /Fo"Debug\" /Fd"Debug\vc100.pdb" /Gd /analyze- /errorReport:queue
```

And here are the **linker** command lines:

VS 2008

```
/OUT:"c:\temp\myproj\myproj\Debug\myproj.exe" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:"Debug\myproj.exe.intermediate.manifest" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:"c:\temp\myproj\myproj\Debug\myproj.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X86 /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib
```

VS 2010

```
/OUT:"c:\temp\myproj2\Debug\myproj2.exe" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /MANIFEST /ManifestFile:"Debug\myproj2.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ALLOWISOLATION /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:"c:\temp\myproj2\Debug\myproj2.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /PGD:"c:\temp\myproj2\Debug\myproj2.pgd" /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X86 /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE
```

**EDIT**
Answers to questions from comments:

Running VS 2008 version from command line (release build): ~3 seconds

Running VS 2010 version from command line (release build): ~1.5 seconds

(these times seem to be similar to the times running directly from VS IDE)

Running VS 2008 version from command line (debug build): ~10.5 seconds

Running VS 2010 version from command line (debug build): ~49 seconds

code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cctype>
#include <cmath>
#include <complex>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include "time.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {

  clock_t t1,t2;
  t1=clock();

  int A=1069514;
  int B=1946556;

  set< pair< int, int > > vals;
  char buff[1000];
  for(int i = A; i <= B; ++i) {
    sprintf(buff,"%d",i);
    string cur = buff;
    for (int j = 1; j <= (int)cur.size() - 1; ++j) {
      string y=cur.substr(j) + cur.substr(0,j);
      if (y[0]=='0')
        continue;
      int k = atoi(y.c_str());
      if (k > i && k <= B) {
        vals.insert(make_pair(i,k));
      }
    }  
  }

  t2 = clock();
  float secs = ((float)t2 - (float)t1) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  cout<<"took "<<secs<<endl;


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you run the output itself, instead of running it within `VS2010`? The debugger on it does a lot more work than `VS2008`, even if running a release version.

Comment: In addition - measuring perf of a debug build is not useful, what is the comparison of release vs release?

Comment: @K-ballo - There was almost no difference (see my edited answer)

Comment: @Steve Townsend - Yes, release mode is actually faster with the VS 2010 generated version. But why would the debug version be so much slower on VS 2010 than VS 2008?

Comment: My guess would be extra checking in the debug STL. You'd need a code review and/or a profiler to be sure. Check Microsoft's STL debug settings, they change in each VS revision.  For example : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985982

Comment: Either I'm reading your results wrong, or they are not similar at all

Comment: Debug in VS2010 is slower than debug in VS2008. never validate performance on debug release.

Comment: @K-ballo - If you look at the second set of numbers in my EDIT, the numbers are similar (e.g. 10.5 vs 10.459 and 49 vs 47.043.

Comment: @Max - I realize that, but I wouldn't expect it to be *4 to 5* times as slow from VS 2008 vs VS 2010, even though it's debug mode.

Comment: @dcp: Don't your results show that `VS2010` release is twice as fast as the one from `VS2008`? Have you tried running the debug versions from outside VS as well? I told you `VS2010`'s debugger offer much much more features than the one in `VS2008` so its expected for programs to run slower **if** they are actually being debugged.

Comment: @K-ballo - yes, in release mode VS 2010's version is faster. But in debug mode, VS 2010's version is 4-5 times slower.

Comment: But _who cares_? Optimizations disabled == lousy performance, this is no surprise.

Comment: @ildjarn - Well, in the case of something like a programming competition (google code jam, for example), I typically write the code and debug it, then I have to download the test file from google, run it, and send in my output to the google grader. So now I have to do a release build of my program instead of using the debug build. It's just an extra step. Anyway, it just seems strange that debug mode on VS 2008 is 4-5 times faster than 2010. Lousy performance, true, but 4-5 times more lousy from one version of VS to the next? Seems a bit extreme, wouldn't you say?

Comment: @ildjam - I forgot to mention, once you download the file from google, you have 4 minutes to upload your program output, so that's why program speed matters a lot.

Comment: @dcp: For competition problems, you're probably taking about the difference between 1ms and 5ms... trivial compared to your response time.  For larger problems, yes you'd better be compiling with optimizations if you care about speed.